# How to override WooCommerce custom taxonomy term archive Template in Plugin

Tags: wordpress, templates, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I am creating a separate plugin for Default / Custom Taxonomy.
My requirement is to **Override** **WooCommerce Custom Taxonomy Template** in my **Custom Plugin**.

I am using the following code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_locate_template', 'override_woocommerce_template_cust', 10, 3 );
public function override_woocommerce_template_cust( $template, $template_name, $template_path ) {
    if ( is_tax() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ) {
        $template = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/cust-taxonomy.php';
    }
    return $template;
}
```

Now this code working fine for existing **"Categories" and "Tags"**
But , not working for **WooCommerce Custom Taxonomy**.

For **WooCommerce Custom Taxonomy** , my custom template is being called , and WooCommerce template is also being called , and that's why adding more and more products after FOOTER ( Please check screen-shot )

[image]

[image]

**Edit 1 :
How do I override ALL the custom/in-built taxonomy term archive template ?
I want to override ALL the custom/in-built taxonomy term archive template
like : Category, Tag, WooCommerce Category, WooCommerce Tag, Any Custom Taxonomy, LearnDash Category etc ...**

Answer (score -1):

[Take a look at the Codex:](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#Custom_Taxonomies_display)

> - `taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php` - If the taxonomy were sometax, and taxonomy's term were someterm WordPress would look for `taxonomy-sometax-someterm.php.` In the case of Post Formats, the taxonomy is 'post_format' and the terms are `post-format-{format}.`
>   i.e. `taxonomy-post_format-post-format-link.php`
> - `taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php` - If the taxonomy were sometax, WordPress would look for `taxonomy-sometax.php`
> - `taxonomy.php`

You registered your taxonomy as `product_categories`, so you should be using `taxonomy-product_categories.php` to create a template for all terms in that particular taxonomy.

Use `taxonomy-product_categories-furniture.php` to target only the one term referenced in your URL.

`taxonomy.php` will be used for all taxonomies.

Comment: Thanks for answer 
I am not looking for any specific term override 

I want to override template for ALL the term of custom / default taxonomy